# Impact on Firewall with IP camera network attached

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

We recently ran a independent fiber network for a deployment of around 150 IP cameras around our property.  Needing something to pass out IP addresses, and enable access from our current LAN, I was debating on whether or not to put it on a separate firewall to lessen the impact on our main firewall.  If I just connect it to a different interface on our Sonicwall NSA2600, will it impact the firewall performance much?  All the traffic would be on the new fiber LAN, and would be recording to the NVR.  Would I be better off setting up a different firewall?  Or should the impact be minimal.

[image]

Comment: What do you think might impact the performance? Video recording traffic will stay local, only viewing video from the LAN will travel through the firewall. How many people will be watching the videos? You mention address assignment, but assigning addresses to 150 shouldn't really be a lot of work.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wanted to be certain.  There is going to be 8 VPN tunnels coming to that firewall, as well as acting as the main firewall for our main office, I just didn't want to overwork it.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that most of the CCTV traffic will be confined to the LAN under X6 traffic because communication is between your cameras and the recording device.

Also, I understand that the only traffic that will flow throught X6 will be things like camera control, DNS, updating firmware, etc. I mean, there are no heavy traffic from CCTV LAN to the rest of Firewalls interfaces.

If this two suppositions are correct, your firewall won't notice the new X6 LAN.

If this two suppositions are incorrect, comment what it's different.

Comment: Yea you are correct, just wanted to be certain.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A firewall is typically not used as a network core/aggregation device.  Idustry practise is to use a multilayer switch to act as the core/aggregation point for your different networks/subnetworks.